# iPad crashes when running iPhone app in compatibility mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I just had one of my apps reviewed, and I never knew this but apparently an iPhone specific app must also be able to run on the iPad in compatibility mode... I never knew this, and it doesn't really make sense.

Anyways, my app is crashing when calling didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *rootViewController;
    rootViewController = [[[WPViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WPViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.viewController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController] autorelease];
    self.viewController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

Using NSLog, I can see that it crashes when I call [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; And also, if I remove that line of code and run it in the iPad simulator, it does not crash, but obviously shows a blank screen. The app runs fine on the iPhone simulator

Any ideas? or places to start looking?

Comment: I wonder if your auto-releasing of the window is causing it to nil out.  Usually, top-level objects are released and `nil`'ed out in `-dealloc`, not autoreleased.  What does the log say when it crashes?

Comment: That's a great point, I just tried removing the autorelease and it's still crashing.

All I'm getting is an lldb exc_bad_access on 0x1713d4c:  calll  0x1713d51                 ; __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 + 17

Which is caused by somewhere in the program trying to access a pointer that is nil, or has no data right?

Comment: that error means that you are trying to use deallocated object. add "All exceptions" breakpoint and run your program in debug mode.

Comment: Remove all your autorelease calls, and shift your release code into dealloc.

Comment: I removed all of my autorelease calls from the app delegate and I'm still receiving the error. Even so if I comment out all of my code in my view controller and simply load the view

Comment: Does that mean it's in my nib/xib that's causing an issue? Or?..

Comment: Put a breakpoint down, not just an NSLog.

Comment: Are you making the UI through xib?